# Multithreaded aws function

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I asked a related question on creating parallel processes in a python lambda function and I'm more curious on how to tackle a specific issue on max_pool_sizes. I'm using the threading module and in short my issue is trying to access multiple files from S3 to retrieve data from all of them simultaneously. Currently it seems that there is a max_pool_size attribute that is preventing me from getting everything I need. As a result I get this error `Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.amazonaws.com` Has anyone else had a similar error or have any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambda, right? It's purely a boto3 question.

Comment: Yes. Lambda is just background info.

Comment: Great, then I've removed "lambda" from your question's title and tags. It sounds like you've got a question about `boto3`; if that's correct then I suggest you add "boto3" to your question's title and tags.

Comment: The `discarding connection` message doesn't necessarily indicate a problem; what makes you think it is? Also: if you really feel the need, you can [manually configure your boto session](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config.html), though I'm skeptical that it will solve your problem (whatever problem that is).

Comment: It's not so much a terminal problem. It's just an efficiency issue. Some processes that should ideally take 5 seconds end up taking 80 seconds when they occur in parallel which I concluded is because of this. It's been a while since I looked at this exact project, and I managed to make improvements although I didn't completely resolve the issue. Any recommendations would still be ideal! (I alerady did the configurations that definitely helped the issue significantly)

Comment: `max_pool_size` is not necessarily the problem, but without seeing any code, it's hard to tell why your script is running slower than you expecteded.

Answer (score 1):

You may examine ClientConfiguration class and use setMaxConnections(int maxConnections) method for this purpose. Take a look on this link:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to use boto3 sdk for python. Thanks for the heads up maybe boto has similar layouts

Comment: Either way you pointed me to a great solution thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and found a solution on the AWS Compute blog. I'm linking below for future readers of this thread:

> [Parallel Processing in Python with AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/) (by Oz Akan, Sep/2017, AWS Compute blog)